# Ajax or Django Rest Framework is acting weird with Post Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am building a Kanban Board with jQuery / JS Frontend and Django / DRF Backend.

I am sending a POST AJAX Request to Server

```js
function login(email, password) {

  var d = {
    "email": email,
    "password": password
  }

  d = JSON.stringify(d)

  console.log(d)
  return $.ajax({
    url: "api/accounts/login/",
    type: "POST",
    data: d,
    dataType: "json",
  }).then((response) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    return data;
  }).fail((response) => {
    return false;
  })
}
```

But when the request is received by the server this

```
{"email":"satyam@gmail.com","password":"satyam@789"}
```

is converted to

```
'{"email": "satyam@gmail.com", "password": "satyam@789"}': ['']}'
```

Django Code

```py
class TodoView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
        data = {'token': token}

        try:
            valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
            user = valid_data["user"]
            request.user = user
        except ValidationError as v:
            print("Validation Error", v)

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(request.data)
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response({"todo": serializer.data})

        return Response({"error": "Invalid Data"})
```

What is the problem causing this?

Is it Javascript or DRF?

Comment: Where do you see the converted result exactly? And what is your expected result?

Comment: I see the converted result in Django, I am trying to save that first json data in DB with Django but it is converting it into second JSON in server which is not valid as per defined serializer

Comment: Can you share the related DRF code? (like your model, view and serializer)

Comment: @KutayAslan added!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're logged in (meaning you have a valid token so your request made it inside to your authentication required view then you don't need to try to login again (I guess that is what you're trying to do). So the code below is redundant/wrong and should be deleted from your view.

```
    token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
    data = {'token': token}

    try:
        valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
        user = valid_data["user"]
        request.user = user
    except ValidationError as v:
        print("Validation Error", v)
```

And I guess you're talking about the TodoSerializer (probably has email and password fields which doesn't make sense either because those fields do not belong to ToDo semantically) instance .data returns in the wrong format. That might be caused by the serializer instantiation below:

```
serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, many=True)
```

`many=True` should be deleted from there since your payload is not a list.
That might solve your problem.

Comment: I got the problem, it was because of not sending the request as a list, I am sending multiple todo's which are cached in local storage in a request every 10 mins or on logout. I converted Verifying part in Middleware and it is verifying correctly and i have created foreign key for User in model. Thanks for taking out time and helping me!!!